# Anyone using GoDaddy Grid Hosting with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting, cloud

I very recently released my ASP.NET MVC based website. I'm beginning planning for when I need to upgrade hosting. I'd like to move to a cloud computing provider and I saw that GoDaddy has a grid hosting solution in beta.

Anyone tried to deploy an ASP.NET MVC web app to the GoDaddy grid hosting? If so, how was the experience? According to their help docs, it seems a lot easier to use than other cloud hosting providers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this like Amazon E2, can you RDP into the boxes?

Comment: Not sure... I haven't tried either Amazon E2 or the GoDaddy grid hosting. I'm pondering moving to the cloud computing host, but most seem incredible expensive for my needs at this time. GoDaddy's looks affordable, but I'm concerned about it's capability to host an ASP.NET MVC website...

Comment: No.  It's like a 'cloudy' version of shared hosting.

Comment: @Dan Esparza - I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a lot of bad reviews about Godaddy grid hosting so I personally haven't tried it.

If you're interested in grid hosting, you should consider the [Microsoft Azure platform](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/default.mspx).

People have been using ASP.NET MVC on Azure: http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2008/11/01/run-aspnet-mvc-on-windows-azure/

Comment: I thought about Windows Azure... but it looked like the MVC app had to be retooled to work with it. Have you tried to use Windows Azure by chance? I wonder how difficult it would be to get an existing app reworked to be hosted from Windows Azure.

Comment: I haven't used Azure yet. It looks really promising though.

Comment: @Chad: It's a Microsoft product running Microsoft code. I haven't gotten to try it yet, but my understanding is that it's unlikely apps need much (if any) modification to work on Azure.

Comment: @ehdv: Yea, you're probably right but I'm not ready for the costs involved... quite  yet. The hosting I've got now, for ~$180/year runs great and has enough resources for now. Always good to be prepared though, thx!

Answer (score 2):

My site is running on GoDaddy Grid (Windows/Unlimited) and I'm using MVC. All seems to work well, though I haven't really noticed any increased reliability over the standard shared hosting.

Comment: have you had any luck working with an EDMX linked to a GoDaddy SQL Server instance? I haven't, I think because I'm using Visual Studio 2010.